# Not getting passport stamped when entering USA from abroad

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps

I (a US citizen) recently returned from a trip abroad. When I entered the US via San Francisco (SFO), I had to do a bunch of stuff at a machine: scan my passport, answer a few questions, and take my picture. Then I received a receipt from the machine with a bunch of info on it.

When I walked up to the US Customs Officer, he stamped my receipt, but not my passport. When I got my luggage and passed through the last part of customs, the stamped receipt was taken.

What's the deal? In the past, I would usually get an ADMITTED stamp in my passport.

Comment: I asked the man why can't I have a stamp in my US Passport and he said `We do not stamp American passports in the United States`. This was in Atlanta.

Comment: I agree with Mark answer. I am a US Citizen so is my wife and we traveled to the Dominican Republic 2 years ago and our passports got stamped at JFK when we cameback. We traveled again in 8/2016 and our passports didnt get stamped this time but the kiosk print out. It looks like they are recording your entry electronically. Plus your US passport last 10 years, imagine if you get a stamp every time, you will run out of page.

Comment: @user49890 even if you leave and enter the US four times a year and allow four stamps per page, the US stamps would only use up ten pages, which is less than half.  But most passport holders probably travel less frequently than that, and having more than four stamps per page is quite common, at least in my passport, so running out of pages is not a problem for most people.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As US citizen you do not need a stamp in your passport, as you belong to the country. It is foreigners who need a stamp in their passport, as they can be asked to proof their right to be in the USA if stopped for whatever reason. Especially proof they did not overstay their visa and did not arrive illegally.

Most countries in Europe never gave stamps to their own citizens, nor do they give stamps to other EU citizens. As their citizens and those of other EU countries do not need visa and do not have limits on the time they can spend in the other EU countries.

Within Europe many, or even most, Europeans travel with their ID cards. Those do not have space for stamps. But even when I traveled with a passport I never received a stamp when traveling within the EU, or its predecessors. These days I keep a passport for travels outside Europe, and use my ID card for travels within Europe.
The Chinese border control people must have met more Europeans without stamps in their passports, even passports a few years old.

Comment: Interesting. When I travel with my parents I guess they stamp my book because we go through the non-US citizens line so they just stamp everyone's passport.

Comment: I have been told recently that the USA is/used to be an exception on the 'citizens do not get a stamp' rule.

Comment: I'm a US citizen and I've had my passport stamped every time I reenter the country. Most recently last December. If things have changed, I guess it must be since then.

Comment: I am also a US citizen, flying in & out multiple times each year and rarely get stamped.  This has been the case for many years.  I think it depends on where you enter exit and frequency of travel.  For folks who travel frequently, they don't stamp and use up your pages.  For folks who travel infrequently, they do stamp.

Comment: If you intend to travel to China within the next year it's a good idea to specifically request passport stamping at border control every time you enter or leave a country. Otherwise Chinese border control is likely to detain you and repeatedly ask why there's no passport stamp corresponding to the time period you were in a non-stamping country.

Comment: Regarding your last comment on passports within Europe: It's actually a rule in the EU (e.g. in the Schengen Borders code but I believe it applies more broadly) that the travel documents of EU citizens (and a few other categories of people) *should not* be stamped, [even if you ask](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/do-croatia-serbia-and-romania-still-give-passport-stamp-travel-from-eu) (although in this case, only Belgium followed the rule scrupulously).

Comment: @Relaxed That's interesting, because a dual US-EU national might like the proof of being outside the US for income tax exemption. (Of course, you can also prove this with airline tickets, but the passport can be a one-stop calendar.)

Comment: @Relaxed "although in this case, only Belgium followed the rule scrupulously" Sweden does too I can testify. I'm Swedish, and it's only there that they consistently refuse to stamp the blank stamp sheet I sometimes bring on trips. Mind you, it's usually easier to get EU countries to stamp a sheet than an EU passport.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus such a person could enter the EU with the US passport to get a stamp.

Answer (score 12):

If you used an Automatic Passport Control (APC) machine, you will not receive an "Admitted" stamp. It should have been stamped onto the print out instead.

Admitted stamps are sometimes presented in US Passports by US CBP: Wikipedia is ever helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Us_stamp_2.png You can see that the "you must leave by" line has been left blank. However apparently it is not universal. You can ask if you want one.
See this web link for some more reports: http://ask.metafilter.com/205231/To-stamp-or-not-to-stamp

I am told by colleagues that it is helpful to have a stamp for filling out tax returns if you are domiciled outside the USA and wish to prove how much time you spend outside the US.

Comment: That's a good point about tax returns.

Comment: I believe that time spent outside the US can be significant even if you are domiciled in the US, though that might only be true for state taxes.  I just remember that it was always an issue for my father when he was traveling a lot for work.

Answer (score 6):

Stamping is not a must. These days technology is catching up fast, everything is recorded electronically. The moment you, airline or the passport control officer scan your passport, the job is done. Stamps are a mess, though it looks good it consumes space in passport for frequent travelers.

I have traveled to all countries in Europe (as non EU citizen, holding residence EU permit), some countries dont even care to stamp, they just scan my permit or passport and wave me. It happened many times, but sometimes i get stamped the good old way :))

The bottom line is you dont need to worry too much about stamping, that is the job of border control, i am sure they know how to play the rules safe. All you have to do is just enjoy the travels, and rest will be taken care of :))

Comment: There are rules about this. You *should* get a stamp if you have a regular permit, but not if you have a permit as “member of the family of an EU citizens”. Guards are sometimes sloppy about it but legally speaking it's not up to them. For people without a residence permits, stamps are actually quite important in the Schengen area – which does not have any shared database of entries and exits – and you do occasionally need to worry about them.

Comment: Yes i asked the guards about the stamp, they tell me because i hold RP of a member state, there is no need for that. They scan my RP and check my passport and let me through :)

Comment: I can easily believe that but they are wrong. It's only for specific types of residence permits that they are not supposed to put stamps.

Comment: @Relaxed Actually there seem to be national rules regarding stamping people with ordinary residence Permits. I know that in Sweden and France (and Hungary *if I recall correctly*), they are supposed to do it, but not in Switzerland and Slovenia. I've consistently noticed it to be the case in said countries

Comment: @Crazydre I guess it depends on what we mean by "rules" and “supposed to”. Maybe border guards have official instructions and consistently follow them but my reading of the Schengen Border Codes is that the actual rule is as I described above and that's not really up to each individual country, legally speaking.

Comment: @Relaxed Could you please link it? It may be the rule officially, but at least *de facto* I can tell you with certainty that it varies between countries. Besides the fact that I regularly try observing the pattern at borders where non-EU/EFTA nationals cross, I have a Filipina friend with a Swedish permanent residence permit, and she did **not** get stamped the three times she exited and re-entered at Zurich, but **always** at Stockholm-Arlanda

Comment: @Relaxed Also "These days technology is catching up fast, everything is recorded electronically" is simply not true. Several countries (but not all) record entries and exits for *their own* records, so if the exit is done in another Schengen country, stamps remain the key factor. Switzerland, for example, doesn't record entries/exits *at all* or else I would've been told off numerous times by now for entering the transit area simply for plane spotting.

Comment: @Crazydre Sure, I certainly would have never written anything like that, I believe I have made this point countless times on this site… Although to be completely accurate, there are actually plans underway to have some sort of Schengen-wide database of entries and exits in the near future. Beyond that, three times at a single airport isn't much to establish all border guards in a country would do the same, but as I wrote just above, I don't doubt it might be the case, it just wouldn't be a legitimate rule (can't link right now, EUR-LEX seems to be down).

Comment: @Relaxed Yup, I've read about it. Question is if stamps will be completely abolished then