# question on stamping

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, passport-stamps

Do you need a stamp for coming back into California even though you are America citizen and you were born in California.? I have read on your site that you only need a visa and passport to come back to the states and not a stamp. Is that correct. Do you need a stamp for coming back into California even though you are a citizen and born and raised in California?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You are an American citizen? Do you have a valid US passport?

Comment: You do not need a visa if you are an American citizen; in fact, if you can prove it to the border official's satisfaction, you don't need a passport (although the airline won't let you board without one). And a stamp is what happens at the border, not before. Please supply more detail.

Comment: You are returning to California from where?  By what mode of transportation?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something. Please state exactly what you're trying to do, rather than what you think you might need to accomplish that. (For example, "I am an American citizen living in [the place where I live]. What documents do I need to travel to the USA and how do I get them?") Note that travelling to California is the same as travelling to anywhere else in the USA, and being born in California is also the same as being born anywhere else in the USA. Also, if you're already in the USA, the answer is "You don't need anything. Just go to California."

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of confusion in your post. I'll try to answer, but if you could provide more information, we could help you better.

First, if you were born in the United States, and you didn't renounce your US citizenship, you are a US citizen (if you were the child of a foreign diplomat serving in the US at the time, you might not be a US citizen by birth, but we'll set that aside because it's complicated).

US citizens do not need, and will not receive, a visa to enter the United States. US citizens [must have and use a valid US passport](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality/dual-nationality.html) to enter and exit the US. You'll need to show a valid US passport to the airline representatives (to demonstrate that you'll be allowed into the US) and to the immigration officer when you arrive. You do not need to obtain any kind of stamp. If you don't have a valid US passport, you should get one before you travel.

The only point where a stamp is involved for a US citizen is after you've presented the immigration officer your passport. He or she will examine the passport to ensure that it is valid and belongs to you and may then [stamp it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Us_stamp_2.png) just to show that you entered the United States. It is also possible that you won't receive such a stamp (you likely [won't get a stamp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49302/not-getting-passport-stamped-when-entering-usa-from-abroad) if you use one of the automated passport kiosks). It doesn't matter; no stamp at the border is required for US citizens.

Note also that this all applies to entering the entire United States, not just the one state of California. Once you are already in the United States, no passports or stamps or visas are required or involved specifically to enter California or travel between any states (note that some sort of [ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) is required to fly within the US, and a passport is one of the options).