# Why wasn't my passport stamped at the US border?

Tags: usa, passport-stamps

My friend and I (both visa nationals) were traveling from Canada to the US by bus last weekend. To my surprise, the immigration officer didn't stamp either of our passports and instead simply waved us through after scanning our documents. The entry was properly recorded, but I can't help but wonder if we didn't break some law by entering the country without a passport stamp.

What's the reason behind the lack of a stamp? Isn't it mandatory for non-Canadian visitors?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49302/not-getting-passport-stamped-when-entering-usa-from-abroad (that question is about a US national)

Comment: Probably a mistake. CBP website says passports are to be stamped: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/i-94-instructions/i94-rollout

Comment: What nationality are you?  Have you entered the US on another occasion during the past few months?

Comment: @Doc European, with B1/B2 visas and valid I-94. My passport was stamped in the same situation two weeks ago.

Comment: Dude: if *they* didn't stamp your passport then *you* didn't break any law.

Comment: i had entered feb 6 / 2019 and they didt stamp my pasport. Iam from colombia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you entered the US under *automatic revalidation*.

Under automatic revalidation, people who have been admitted to the US in a non-immigrant status can travel to Canada or Mexico (and, for F and J visa holders and VWP participants, various Caribbean islands) for up to 30 days and return to the US under the same admission that they had previously entered under.

This is the so-called 90 day rule that people mention when talking about visiting these places from the US: Because you are admitted under your previous entry, you don't get a new 90 day admission; instead, your previous 90-day admission still applies and you must depart the US before that date.

Comment: So you're not supposed to get a fresh passport stamp if you have a valid I-94 already?

Comment: @JonathanReez In my experience, a new I-94 was created to show the latest entry point and date. I'm not sure until when it was valid but I guess it was the same date as the original. (Passport was only stamped on the first entry)

Comment: @JonathanReez I've never heard of anyone getting a new stamp when they reenter under automatic revalidation. You can always check your I-94 online and see what it says.

Comment: My I-94 was issued in early February and I've visited the US 4 times since then without getting a fresh I-94. On the first 3 times I got a new passport stamp, but not on the 4th visit. Then perhaps *not* getting a stamp is the correct scenario?

Comment: I believe those entering under automatic revalidation are supposed to get a fresh stamp.  But re-using an existing I-94 isn't exactly the same as automatic revalidation.

Comment: Technically "Automatic Re-validation" and the "90 day rule" are unrelated.  The former is only for people with a US visa, whilst the latter is for people entering under the visa waiver program.  Conceptually they are similar, but technically they are different.

Comment: @Doc Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm too lazy to look up the regulation number covering it, but the full name should be enough - "Automatic VISA Revalidation".  You can't use automatic visa revalidation if you don't hold a visa...

Comment: OK, seems I wasn't that lazy.  22 CFR 41.112(d)(1)(i)

Comment: @Doc it seems in practice that CBP has blended the two somewhat (without regulations as far as I can see) such that those with visas can "re-use" their I-94, nominally under automatic revalidation, even if their visa hasn't expired.  As far as I can see, a strict reading of the automatic revalidations offers no support for that practice.